# Looping through unsaved entity object and get properties and values except non-scalar properties

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the code below to loop through an unsaved entity object.

```
BPCategory Bp = new BPCategory();
Bp.Category = Category;
Bp.PercentShare = PercentShare;
Bp.BPCategory1 = BPCategory;
Bp.DealerCode = Convert.ToString(Global.DealerCode);
Bp.Status = Inactive;

context.BPCategories.AddObject(Bp);

var values = Bp.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x =>
    new
    {
        property = x.Name,
        value = x.GetValue(Bp, null)
    }).ToDictionary(x => x.property, y => y.value);

    foreach (var items in values)
    {
        //some code
    }
context.SaveChanges();
```

The problem with this is non-scalar properties are getting included in `values` which is i don't intend to include. Is there any way i can remove non-scalar properties from `values`?

See the image below. How to not include `EntityState` and `EntityKey`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom navigation attribute class, which will help you to detect scalar or non-scalar properties at reflection time.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class NavigationAttribute: Attribute
{

}
```

I have tried to write your model class, Product is a demo navigation class, you can use other classes like this way:

```
public class BPCategory 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string PercentShare { get; set; }
    public string BPCategory1 { get; set; }
    public string DealerCode  { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [NavigationAttribute]
    public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
}
```

**Implement this code to your code:**

```
var values = Bp.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NavigationAttribute), false).Count() != 1)
            .Select(x =>
            new
            {
                property = x.Name,
                value = x.GetValue(Bp, null)
            }).ToDictionary(x => x.property, y => y.value);
```

Output: only scalar properties, and without Product:

```
Id, Category, PercentShare, BPCategory1, DealerCode,Status
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting the idea. But how would i implement this on my code? I always end up getting the EntityState and EntityKey

Comment: Just edited my answer , you can try to get only scalar properties with key,value pairs.

Comment: `EntityState` and `EntityKey` are still getting included in the collection. Where should i put the `NavigationAttribute' class?

Comment: Let me know which properties are non-scalar, i think BPCategory1 is non-scalar, if non-scalar, add [NavigationAttribute] top of the property like i added in Product. i have checked your code in my local machine its returning only scalar Dictionary values.

Comment: all of BPCategory properties are from my entity model generated from BPCategory table except the `EntityState` and `EntityKey`.

Comment: could you please send me the output of values variable, i am getting like this: [{Key:Id, Value:""}]

Comment: Please see the image that i've included on my post. I've tried `x => x.property != "EntityState"` but i can't seem to get it work

Comment: ok , i have attached an image to my answer. i don't know how actually you are doing. please chk my answer carefully , if no result i'll send my code to you using google drive. Thanks

Comment: I think it has something to do with where I'm placing `NavigationAttribute` class

Comment: Just Create a class with name NavigationAttribute after BPCategory  .  or anywhere, and use this class as Attribute.

Comment: `BPCategory` is generated from my dbcontext edmx model. Does that work the same with your `BPCategory` class?

Answer (score 1):

`BindingFlags` did the trick. Setting the `GetProperties()` argument to `.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)` removed the `EntityState` and `EntityKey` properties from the dictionary

```
var values = Bp.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(x =>
    new
        {
            property = x.Name,
            value = x.GetValue(Bp, null)
        }).ToDictionary(x => x.property, y => y.value.ToString());
```

Comment: Good Work @onhax